# Can't boot from USB on Dell Inspiron

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 (5000 series) and am trying to dual-boot Windows 10 (already installed) and Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I have a bootable USB stick, which I made using the ISO file from Ubuntu's website, and UNetBootIn (I have also tried this with a stick made from Rufus). However, when I try to boot from the USB to install Ubuntu, I am unable to do so.

I have tried booting from a USB drive on Legacy BIOS, which does start booting up Ubuntu, but it freezes a few seconds into the boot process. I have also tried booting on the standard UEFI, but adding grub (specifically, EFI/grubx64.efi on my USB stick) as a boot option. Note that when I do this, I disable Secure Boot. This does bring me to the standard grub screen, and I can click "Try Ubuntu without Installing", but it freezes on the load screen.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

so i had erorr in dell inspiron 7559 too. You can fix it:
1. boot = USB (with UEFI) and push button 'e' on your keyboard
2. find line "quiet flash" and replace as "nomodeset=0" (or "nvidia.nomodeset=0" if your graphic card is NDIVIA)
3. Press F10 and boot. Finish
good luck!